# Java Swing: JPanels painting over each other

Tags: java, swing

Alright, so I have two JFrames each with a different implementation of JPanel sitting inside of them. When I call `repaint()` on the JPanels, what is painted on one JPanel also becomes painted on the other JPanel.

I know I could take care of this by calling something like `g.clearRect()`, but there are too many components to repaint every time.

Any idea why this is happening?

```
//This makes the two JFrames and JPanels, sets everything up

public void makeSpaceSimulation() {
    int dimen = 10000;
    int scale = 20;
    int numOfClusters = 30;
    int planPerCluster = 2000;
    SpaceShip s = new SpaceShip(dimen, scale);

    QuadTree t = new QuadTree(dimen, 20);
    new PlanetCreationTest(t, dimen, scale, numOfClusters, planPerCluster);

    makeMap(dimen, scale, s, t);
    makePOV(s, t, scale, dimen);
}

public void makeMap(int dimen, int scale, SpaceShip s, QuadTree t) {

    final JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setSize(dimen / scale, dimen / scale);
    f.setLocation(0, 0);
    f.setTitle("Map Panel");
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    mapP = new MapPanel(scale, s, dimen);
    mapP.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    mapP.addTree(t);

    f.add(mapP);
    f.setVisible(true);
    Insets i = f.getInsets();
    f.setSize(dimen / scale + (i.left + i.right) + 2, dimen / scale
            + (i.top + i.bottom) + 2);

    Thread th = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                mapP.repaint();
            }

        }
    };
    th.start();

}

public void makePOV(final SpaceShip s, QuadTree t, int scale, int dimen) {
    Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setSize(500, 500);
    f.setLocation(screenSize.width - 500, 0);
    f.setTitle("POV Panel");
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    povP = new POVPanel(s, scale, dimen);
    povP.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    povP.addTree(t);
    povP.setFocusable(true);

    povP.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
            final int i = arg0.getKeyCode();
            Thread th = new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    if (i == 39) {
                        s.moveRight();
                    } else if (i == 37) {
                        s.moveLeft();
                    } else if (i == 40) {
                        s.moveDown();
                    } else if (i == 38) {
                        s.moveUp();
                    }
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            };
            th.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {

        }

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {

        }

    });

    f.add(povP);
    f.setVisible(true);
    Insets i = f.getInsets();
    f.setSize(dimen / 20 + (i.left + i.right) + 2, dimen / 20
            + (i.top + i.bottom) + 2);

    Thread th = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                povP.repaint();
            }

        }
    };
    th.start();

}

//here's the MapPanel

public class MapPanel extends JPanel {

private QuadTree q;
private int scale;
private int dimen;
private SpaceShip s;
private boolean firstDraw;

public MapPanel(int scale, SpaceShip s, int dimen) {
    this.dimen = dimen;
    q = new QuadTree(0, 0);
    this.scale = scale;
    this.s = s;
    firstDraw = true;
}

public void addTree(QuadTree q) {
    this.q = q;

}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    if (firstDraw) {
        q.draw(g, scale, new Point(0, 0));
        s.drawScaledGeometry(g);
        System.out.println("Totally drew that");
        firstDraw = false;
    } else {
        g.clearRect(s.viewDistance.x/scale, s.viewDistance.y/scale,
                s.viewDistance.width/scale, s.viewDistance.height/scale);
        q.quadDraw(g, scale, s.viewDistance, new Point(0, 0));
        s.drawScaledGeometry(g);
    }
}
```

}

```
//and this is the POVPanel 

public POVPanel(SpaceShip s, int scale, int dimen) {
    super();
    this.s = s;
    // this.scale = scale;
    this.dimen = dimen;
}

public void addTree(QuadTree q) {
    this.q = q;
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.clearRect(0, 0, dimen / 20, dimen / 20);
    q.quadDraw(g, 1, s.viewDistance, s.getMoved());
    s.drawGeometry(g);
}
```

Comment: No idea on what is happening because you have not posted any code so far.

Comment: Doing custom painting, not call `super.paintXxx` - naughty you

Comment: Sorry, added the code. Yeah, I don't know why I added the super.paintXXX into there I was just desperate enough to be an idiot I suppose.

Comment: @BillKeller You are honor bound to call `super.paintComponent` (or what ever paint method you've overridden).  The paint methods are complex methods and you should have an extremely good reason for not making a call to there `super`.  Breaking the chain will break your soul (as you waste time trying to figure out why nothing works)

Comment: @BillKeller, to notify someone in comments use `@` and then person's name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is (one) of your problems...

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    if (firstDraw) {
        q.draw(g, scale, new Point(0, 0));
        s.drawScaledGeometry(g);
        System.out.println("Totally drew that");
        firstDraw = false;
    } else {
        g.clearRect(s.viewDistance.x/scale, s.viewDistance.y/scale,
            s.viewDistance.width/scale, s.viewDistance.height/scale);
        q.quadDraw(g, scale, s.viewDistance, new Point(0, 0));
        s.drawScaledGeometry(g);
    }
}
```

The `Graphics` context is shared during the paint cycle, meaning when you get it, you will be getting the same context used to paint all the other components on the screen.

You MUST call `super.paintComponent(g)`, which will take care of preparing the graphics context for this component to start painting.

**Update #1**

Again...

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g); // <-- Call me instead...
    //g.clearRect(0, 0, dimen / 20, dimen / 20);
    q.quadDraw(g, 1, s.viewDistance, s.getMoved());
    s.drawGeometry(g);
}
```

**Update #2**

I'm also seriously concerned by this

```
while (true) {
    mapP.repaint();
}
```

This could seriously impact the performance of you application.  You DO NOT control the paint cycle, that's the responsibility of the repaint manager.  The repaint manager will decide when a repaint is required.  Calling `repaint` repetitively like this could actually cause the repaint manager to delay actually scheduling a paint cycle.

Much better to use a [`javax.swing.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html), it's simpler and safer...

```
Timer timer = new Timer(25, new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        mapP.repaint();
    }
});
timer.setRepeats(true);
timer.setCoalesce(true);
timer.start();
```

You might find reading through

- [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)
- [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)

Helpful

**Update #3**

Avoid `KeyListener`, it will only make you cry.  Instead, use the [key bindings API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Comment: You're a goddamned helpful guy. Thank you!

Comment: You are amazing! Such a detailed and long answer!

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov Yeah, my fingers hurt ;)